# High-density IoT solution

Tags: wireless, router, networking

The environment: Industrial warehouse. 200 custom Arduino ESP32. Router: ASUS RT-AC68U. Access point: Ruckus 9U1-R510-WW00

Issue: High reconnection rate for the Arduino devices. Initially, we only used the router and had about 100 reconnects per hour with an average reconnection time of 1 minute. By adding the AP we have lowered the time a device spends disconnected. But now we have 2000 reconnects per hour with a reconnection time of 5 seconds.

Desired outcome: We would like to set up a network architecture with a stable Wifi connection.

Further notes: We have solved all software issues, such as ghost connections.

Is there a router that can guarantee a stable connection for 200 devices? If we only use 50 devices, the disconnection/reconnection rate is very close to zero.

Comment: You usually pay for what you get. Based on my short experience, internal processor and ram are very important. This information is hard to get in some manufacturets but a good indicative is the maximum number of clients and the price (sometimes a high number of clients doesn't mean a fast response). Did you have a look to Ubiquiti and Lancom?